# Adding 2 additional pages to the end of a crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report for orders and i would like to add 2 pages at the end of the order. My order is most of the time 1 page, sometimes it will be 2 pages. So I want to add my terms & conditions to the end of it. This terms&conditions is always 2 pages.

I tried to add a text object in the report footer. Than in Section Expert, I select Report footer --> and Check the New Page Before ( I also tried it with the New Page After)
I also suppress the sections that I don't want to appear on the 2 last pages by using : **PageNumber > TotalPageCount - 2**

As far as this all works, but if I open my report. On the second page of the report you see the beginning of the terms&conditions. On the third page of the report you will see also de terms&conditions. But the second portion of the first page, of the terms&conditions, is also on the second page of the terms&conditions. therefore, there is always a part of the text that is duplicated

**For example**: my example of terms&conditions exist of 14 points. On the first page of the terms you will see point 1 to point 8. on the second page you will see point 6 to point 10. and on the third page you will see point 9 to point 14
--> Thats very annoying!!

I also tried it to check **'Suppress if duplicated'** --> but nothing is changing??

Can someone help me with my problem please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the terms and conditions in sub report and place that sub report in report footer

Comment: Accept it as the answer.. so that others can use.